# Se pierden variables de SESSION en chrome al regresar de paypal

Tags: php, html

espero me puedan ayudar u orientar, debo mencionar que soy principiante en php y html

tengo dos paginas php/html que van recolectando informacion de la compra antes de enviar los datos a paypal via post, en la segunda pagina se realiza el envio del formulario de datos a paypal mediante otra pagina php que el usuario no ve, cada pagina tiene inicio de session en su encabezado para ir guardando las variables de session. Una vez se regresa de paypal las variables de session sirven para mostrar al usuario el resumen de su compra y datos de reserva, estos datos se muestran junto a los datos enviados por paypal. En opera y safari las variables de session se conservan hasta el final una vez que se ha retornado de paypal y se reciben los datos de paypal via post tambien, pero en chrome se pierden una vez que se regresa de paypal, ya he buscado pero no encuentro nada que deba arreglar y ademas no entiendo porque en chrome no trabaja bien la session y si en opera y safari.

```
codigo en pagina1, envia datos via form post a pag2
<?php
session_start();
?>

codigo en pagina2 envia datos via form post a pag3
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['vina_booking'] = $_POST['tour_booking'];
$_SESSION['d_booking'] = $_POST['date_booking'];
$_SESSION['time_booking'] = $_POST['time_booking'];
$_SESSION['ad_booking'] = $_POST['nro_ad'];

$tour_booking = $_POST['tour_booking'];
$date_booking = $_POST['date_booking']; 
$time_booking = $_POST['time_booking'];
$nro_ad = $_POST['nro_ad']; 
?>

codigo en pagina3 envia datos via form post a paypal
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['trf_book'] = $_POST['trf_book'];
$_SESSION['firstname_booking'] = $_POST['firstname_booking'];
$_SESSION['lastname_booking'] = $_POST['lastname_booking'];
$_SESSION['email_booking'] = $_POST['email_booking'];
$_SESSION['telephone_booking'] = $_POST['telephone_booking'];
$_SESSION['comentarios_booking'] = $_POST['comentarios_booking'];
?>

codigo en pagina4 recibe datos de paypal y muestra resumen de la compra
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['transaccion'] = $_POST["txn_id"];
$_SESSION['payment_date'] = $_POST["payment_date"];
$_SESSION['payment_status'] = $_POST["payment_status"];
$_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
$_SESSION['$mc_gross'] = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$_SESSION['$item_name'] = $_POST['item_name'];
?>
```

saludos y espero haber escrito bien segun el formato que se requiere
Jorgeg

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna configuración diferente para Cookies y datos de sitios en tu navegador (Google Chrome)?

Comment: Hola, no he realizado ninguna configuracion especial de Cookies

Comment: logre aislar el problema, la diferencia se produce que al retornar de paypal Opera sigue con el mismo session_id() sin embargo chrome genera un nuevo session_id() ... no se como cambiar esto para que pueda seguir con el mismo session_id ...

Comment: alguien sabe como evitar que se destruya la session o retomarla una vez que se regresa de otro sitio como paypal ... aun no logro solucionar este problema

Answer (score 0):

Se que ya es tarde, pero por si a otra persona le ocurre lo mismo. Revisa que no tengas esto en el formulario:

```html
<input name="rm" type="hidden" value="2" />
```

El valor de 2 hace que retorne un "REQUEST_METHOD" del tipo "POST" y parece que a veces pierde la sesión.